# Downloading georeferenced maps from geoportals

Tags: raster, tiles, united-kingdom, geoportal

Is it possible to download georeferenced maps from [Havering London Borough](http://maps.havering.gov.uk/) and [Adur & Worthing Councils](https://www.adur-worthing.gov.uk/maps/adur-local-plan-map/) portals, and if it is, then how?

I tried to use http response (see picture below), however i just got the jpeg image, that is not georeferenced and with the poor resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Web map portals like these sometimes provide download capacities for their data and export functionality for rendered map images, but this specific portal (tried with the Havering one) does not seem to include either.

In the EU the INSPIRE directive may give you some leverage to request certain types of data, but given the current political situation in the UK you may not get lucky.

I don't know of specific UK law implementing the INSPIRE directive in national legislation, but sometimes it helps to nicely ask the data provider / geoportal maintainers to provide a) data to you or b) download/export capacities for everyone.

Comment: There's no requirement under inspire to give data away. Only metadata has to be available. UK intends to keep going with Inspire, for a few more years yet. Brexit doesn't change it

Comment: For national data providers in scope of inspire data themes, there needs to be view and download services, that conform to data models, but these can be behind a paywall